# Changing the style properties via Tritium

Tags: css, moovweb, tritium

Newbie question, I'm working on a simple scenario: Changing the background color and the text of a giving element on my page using Tritium. My page looks like this:

```
<div class="hero" id="hero">
<div id="heroContentShort">
    <div class="heroContentShort">
        <h1 style="text-transform:capitalize;">My Text<span style="text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;"><a href="/pages/new.html" style="color:#FFFFFF">- on Moovweb</a></span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

On my .TS file I have the following:

```
insert("div", class:"cus_title"){
    insert("div", class:"cus_row1"){
      move_here("//div[@id='hero']/div/div/h1")
      attribute("background", "red")
      text("My New Text")
    }
  }
```

The above is successfully changing the text, although is not preserving any format nor is changing the background color to red.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I highly recommend you not do the coloring in tritium. The DOM and the style should be separate. I would recommend you put this at the bottom of your `main.scss` file if you do not want to create your own page. Then you would do:

```
.cus_row1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

That would get the background color to work perfectly, and correctly.

However, if (for some reason) you HAD to do this in tritium, I would instead do this:

```
  insert("div", class:"cus_title"){
    insert("div", class:"cus_row1"){
      move_here("//div[@id='hero']/div/div/h1")
      attribute("style", "background-color: red")
      text("My New Text")
    }
  }
```

The first reason, is that the background attribute is deprecated. Second, the user agent stylesheet can overwrite it. I hope this works for you!